# How do I get the URL of a .jsp (portlet)?

Tags: java, ajax, jsp

I have a view.jsp and I want to load another .jsp via AJAX and need the URL of this .jsp. How do I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `request` variable to get access to instance of [HttpServletRequest](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI%28%29) and the use `getRequestURI` method to construct URL to another JSP by replacing view.jsp with desired value.

Comment: if i try this i get something like "asdf-portlet/view.jsp". so if the browser calls this view it looks like: "http://localhost:8080/asdf-portlet/view.jsp" but there is nothing. am i doing something wrong?